# Viewchild is null

Tags: angular, primeng, angular9, viewchild

(Angular 9)
I need to use ViewChield().This is my html:

```
<input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="code" #inputStudent/>
```

in my ts I do:

```
    @ViewChild('inputStudent', { read: ElementRef }) someInput: Input;
....

ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (this.someInput != null) {
      console.log(this.someInput);
    } else {
      console.log("object null;");
    }

  }
```

the problem is that my ViewChild is null because console prints me `"object null;"`.Anyone can help me?

Comment: there is no problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4qvwyn

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of the problem, for example on stackblitz,

Answer (score 0):

```
@ViewChild("inputStudent",{ static:true}) someInput: ElementRef;
....
console.log(this.someInput.nativeElement.value);
```

Comment: Can you explain how your answer solves the above problem and what you did? Currently you just threw a bit code here, without any explanation.